# Kubernetes image pull from nexus3 docker host is failed

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

We have created a `nexus3` docker host private registry on CentOS machine and same ip details updated on daemon.json under docker folder.

Docker pull and push is working fine.

Same image while trying to kubernetes deploy is failing with image pull state.

```
$ Kubectl run deployname --image=nexus3provaterepo:port/image
```

Before we create secret entries via command `$ Kubectl create secret` with same inform of user ID and password, like `docker login -u userid -p passwd`

Here my problem is image pull is failing from `nexus3` docker host.

Please suggest me how to verify login via kubernetes command and resolve this pull image issue.

Looking yours suggestions, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So when pulling from private repos you need to specify an `imagePullSecret` like such:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: <your-private-image>
  # Specify the secret with your users credentials
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```

You would then use the `kubectl apply -f` functionality, I am not actually sure you can use this in the imperative cli version of running a deployment but all the doucmentation on this can be found at [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)